# Android OpenGL ES missing some components?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm trying to run the "HelloTriangle" example, from [The OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide](http://ptgmedia.pearsoncmg.com/images/9780321502797/samplepages/0321502795_Sample.pdf), in the Android emulator.

I import `egl.EGLConfig` and `opengles.GL10` from `javax.microedition.khronos`, but the `ESContext` type and definitions such as `GL_COMPILE_STATUS` and `GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER` can't be resolved.

I reworked the triangle example somewhat for Android in that I'm using `GLSurfaceView`.  I understand that it is supposed to be used instead of `OpenGLContext` in the newer versions of the SDK.

Am I using a "non-Android" approach to `OpenGL ES`?  If so, what's the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the answer here is that Android does not yet support 2.0.

Comment: yep - you're stuck with 1.0. You can cast the GL10 object to a GL11 object or to a GL11ExtensionPack object and try calling those functions too - but it seems to only work on some devices that support 1.1.